# Alterando lista por referência em R

Tags: r, lista

tenho o seguinte problema. Tenho 5 grafos (por hora, não importará a estrutura de cada grafo, somente que tenho 5 grafos) e coloquei eles dentro de uma list no R. Irei realizar mudanças nesses grafos dentro de um loop que terá 100 laços.

Exemplo:

```
for (i in 1:100){

for(vile in viles){

  if(sample(1:10,1) <= 1){ # Aresta interna aparecer
    graphInverse <- graph.full(6,directed = TRUE) - vile;
    allEdgesInverse <- get.edgelist(graphInverse);
    randomEdge <- sample(1:length(allEdgesInverse[,1]),1);

    if(length(allEdgesInverse[,1]) != 0){ # Se o grafo nao for completo.
      vile[allEdgesInverse[randomEdge,][1],allEdgesInverse[randomEdge,][2]] <- 1;
    }

  }
  if(sample(1:10,1) <= 1){ # Aresta interna desaparecer
      allEdges <- get.edgelist(vile); 
      randomEdge <- sample(1:length(allEdges[,1]),1);
      vile[allEdges[randomEdge,][1],allEdges[randomEdge,][2]] <- NULL #Vertice deletado
  }

}
```

}

Na primeira condição, insiro uma aresta aleatória com probabilidade 0.1 que não existia, já na segunda condição, excluo uma aresta existente com a mesma probabilidade. Essa explicação anterior é só para contextualizar. O meu problema é, a cada laço (do primeiro for) ele começa um novo laço na lista 'viles' (onde contém todos os meus 5 grafos), faço as devidas alterações, mas a minha lista 'viles' na é atualizada, ou seja, no próximo laço, da variável 'i', a minha lista está inalterada, ou seja, os valores ainda são os iniciais. Estou alterando por valor, e não por referência. Alguém poderia me ajudar a encontrar uma estrutura de dados que, assim que altere a vila, a estrutura que guarde essa vila seja atualizada com essa nova vila alterada ou alterar por referência, ao invés de valor.

Answer (score 1):

Quando você faz um `for` da forma `for(i in x)`, o R faz uma cópia do objeto `x` e não o altera em cada iteração.

Um exemplo simples é:

```
> x <- list(a = 1, b =1)
> for(i in x){
+   i <- i + 1
+ }
> x
$a
[1] 1

$b
[1] 1

> x <- list(a = 1, b =1)
> for(i in 1:length(x)){
+   x[[i]] <- x[[i]] + 1
+ }
> x
$a
[1] 2

$b
[1] 2
```

O jeito correto de fazer no seu caso é:

```
for(j in 1:length(viles)){

  if(sample(1:10,1) <= 1){ # Aresta interna aparecer
    graphInverse <- graph.full(6,directed = TRUE) - viles[[j]];
    allEdgesInverse <- get.edgelist(graphInverse);
    randomEdge <- sample(1:length(allEdgesInverse[,1]),1);

    if(length(allEdgesInverse[,1]) != 0){ # Se o grafo nao for completo.
      viles[[j]][allEdgesInverse[randomEdge,][1],allEdgesInverse[randomEdge,][2]] <- 1;
    }

  }
  if(sample(1:10,1) <= 1){ # Aresta interna desaparecer
      allEdges <- get.edgelist(viles[[j]]); 
      randomEdge <- sample(1:length(allEdges[,1]),1);
      viles[[j]][allEdges[randomEdge,][1],allEdges[randomEdge,][2]] <- NULL #Vertice deletado
  }

}
```

Note que troquei todas as referências a `vile`, por `viles[[j]]` além de trocar o vetor percorrido pelo laço.